# pandas get to_sql behind-the-scenes query as string

Tags: python, sql, pandas

In pandas, I would like to get the SQL command that is run when something like `df.to_sql('table', connection, if_exists='append', method='multi')` is run in python.

Meaning the output would look like `'INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...)'`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen the best way to do this is with the `echo` kwarg in the engine. So for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(['Alex','Bob'],[30,40]), columns=["name","age"])

with engine.connect() as conn:
    df.to_sql('users', conn)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
2023-01-18 11:48:38,369 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users ("index", name, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
2023-01-18 11:48:38,369 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00010s] ((0, 'Alex', 30), (1, 'Bob', 40))
```

You can also log it using `logging` and `logging_name="myengine"` keyword arg in the `create_engine` call. See [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#more-on-the-echo-flag) for more information.